# How to get checked rows cell value in a gridview using javascript with asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Am trying to get the gridview cell value from gridview when the row is checked with javascript my code is like this

**Asp.net Code**

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvEquip" DataKeyNames="Fk_ItemID" ClientIDMode="Static" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowDataBound="gvEquip_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0080c0" ForeColor="White" />
 <Columns>                                          
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-inline" id="chkSelect" value="Click" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="IDVal" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Fk_ItemID") %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gridView1Control = document.getElementById('<%= gvEquip.ClientID %>');
    $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {

        var DataKeyName = "";
        $("#<%=gvEquip.ClientID %> input:checkbox[id*=chkSelect]:checked").each(function (item, index) {
            if (DataKeyName.length == 0) {
                DataKeyName = $(this).next($('#IDVal')).val();
            }
            else {
                DataKeyName += "," + $(this).next($('#IDVal')).val();
            }
        });
        alert(DataKeyName);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets selected checkboxes, with parent get container TD element, with next() get next TD, with find get hidden field and with map, get all values.

```
var values = $(".checkbox:checked").parent().next().find("#IDVal").map(function(){return $(this).val();});
```

Convert values to string with comma separated.

```
alert(values.toArray().join());
```

Comment: @Raviteja It returns value list. var values is array. To get ID values,  values.toArray().join() command. I edit my answer.